# How can I blit the frame rate on my screen with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, frame-rate

I know that I can print the fps in the shell using `print(clock.get_fps())`, but I want to blit the fps on the screen while I'm playing.

I tried to use

```
fps_text = game_font.render(clock.get_fps(), True, (255, 255, 0))
win.blit(fps_text, (1000, 100))
```

(font is already initialized, I use it somewhere else in my program)

I get the error `TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes`for the first line of the code.
Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do ?
Thanks for the answers

Comment: `Font.render` first argument is `text`.  You need to give it text, bit you've passed `clock.get_fps()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clock.get_fps()` returns a `float`. The first argument of '`render`' needs to be a `str`.

Do this instead:
`game_font.render(str(clock.get_fps()), True, (255, 255, 0))`

Comment: Yep it works, thanks very much :)
I wrote

 ```game_font.render(str("{:.2f}".format(clock.get_fps())), True, (255, 255, 0))```

so I have just two digits after the dot

Comment: Correction: `clock.get_fps()` returns a . . . `float`.

Comment: @imallet i didn't check before sorry